# Play video inside TableViewCell using AvplayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to play video in `tableViewCell` where the `url's` of video is getting from server.

Here is my Code:

```
cell.ImageViewPost.hidden = YES;
controllerBig = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
//setting the frame of avviewplayer
[controllerBig.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.bounds.size.width,cell.ViewPlayerBig.bounds.size.height)];
avPlayerLayerBig = [AVPlayerLayer layer];
[avPlayerLayerBig setPlayer:player];
avPlayerLayerBig.frame = cell.ViewPlayerBig.layer.bounds;
NSLog(@"%@Layer Frame is::::",avPlayerLayer);
// set the video player on  view
controllerBig.delegate=self;
controllerBig.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
// create an AVPlayer
asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[baseImageURl stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[ArrTotalResult valueForKey:@"post"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] options:nil];
anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
playerBig = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
playerBig.externalPlaybackVideoGravity=AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[playerBig seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
        // create a player view controller
controllerBig.player = playerBig;
[playerBig play];
[cell.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayerBig];
 [cell.ViewPlayerBig addSubview:controllerBig.view];
    }
```

in these table view array i have two values one is image and second is video.i  m sorting the array value with  url extension like if array value contain Video table view cell will laod with video on parrticular index and if it contain the image  cell will load with image then avplayer will hide.

now problem is table view is  getting stuck when relaoding. and not showing the video properly. and also  video is not placed on full cell frame.